# Popping and appending values from one class object to another

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to create the card game War, where two players draw a card, and the player with the higher card rank "appends" the card from the opponent. Here is my code so far:

```
import random

class Card(object):
  def __init__(self, val):
    self.value = val

  def __str__(self):
    return("{}".format(self.value))

  def show(self):
    print("{}".format(self.value))


class Deck:
  def __init__(self):
    self.cards = []
    self.build()

  def build(self):
    for v in {'2' : 0, '3' : 1, '4' : 2, '5' : 3, '6' : 4, '7' : 5, '8' : 6, '9' : 7 , '10' : 8, 'Jack' : 9, 'Queen' : 10, 'King' : 11, 'Ace' : 12}:
      for i in range(0,2):  #suits removed; only prints half of a deck
        self.cards.append(Card(v))

  def divide(self):
    global half
    half = len(self.cards)//2

  def show(self):
    for c in self.cards:
      c.show()

  def shuffle(self):
    for i in range(len(self.cards)-1, 0, -1):
      r = random.randint(0, i)
      self.cards[i], self.cards[r] = self.cards[r], self.cards[i]

  def drawCard(self):
    return self.cards.pop()


class Player:
  def __init__(self, name):
    self.name = name
    self.hand = []

  def draw(self,deck):
    self.hand.append(deck.drawCard())
    return self

  def showHand(self):
    for card in self.hand:
      print(f"{self.name} drew a {card}!")

  def discard(self, opponent):
    print("Card discarded!")
    self.hand.pop()
    self.hand.appendleft(opponent)


deck1 = Deck()
deck2 = Deck()
deck1.shuffle()
deck2.shuffle()
deck1.show()
print()
deck2.show()

print(input("This is a card game known as War"))
print(input("It is a luck-based game where you have to annihilate your opponent's deck"))
print(input("Each player draws a card, and whoever gets the higher value gets the card"))
print(input("Otherwise both players simultaneously draw four extra cards, where the final card determines the higher value, otherwise keep drawing four cards until a higher value is chosen"))
print(input("The winner is the one who gets all of their opponent's cards. Ready, begin!"))

player1 = Player(input('Player 1, pick a name: '))
player2 = Player(input('Player 2, Pick a name: '))
player1.draw(deck1)
player2.draw(deck2)
player1.showHand()
player2.showHand()
player1.discard(player2)
```

So I want to create the method within the `Player` class by utilizing stacks and queues. However, my issue is that I am not sure how appending and popping `list` indices would work between two objects (`player1` and `player2`) and every method I tried so far resulted in an attribute error. Any ways to fix that?

Comment: When posting a question about code that produces an Exception, always include the complete Traceback - copy and paste it then format it as code (select it and type `ctrl-k`)

Comment: See how to create a [mcve]. Delete as much code as possible but you still get the same error. It'll probably be 5-10 lines of code.

Comment: Can you describe how you imagine the working logic in your `Player.discard` method?

Comment: `self.hand.appendleft(opponent)` in the `discard` method produces an attribute error because `hand` is a list. Use a `deque` instead - `self.hand = collections.deque()` in `__init__`. ...[https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque](https://docs.python.org/3/library/collections.html#collections.deque)

Comment: I do not have a collections variable, so how could that work?

Comment: `import collections`